# How to write long formatted text in a Text View with xCode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, controller, textview, uitextview

I feel strange asking a question about what's probably the simplest page in my iPhone app but here it is anyway:

I have a controller that a user can invoke to display the rules of the game and some acknowledgment information.  I set up a Text View object filling up the whole page in Interface Builder and am wondering what's the best way of entering the text I need.

I *can* do all of this in the m file but entering large text sections in a programming language is never fun.

I *can* also simply overwrite the default "Lorem ipsum dolor..." text in Interface Builder but then my return characters don't seem to be taken into account when I run the app.

Is there a better way to fill my Text View with my own formatted text? And how can I format my text neatly and easily (i.e. make titles in bold, underline some words, etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to easily display formatted text in a `UITextView`. The best approach for this kind of problem is to use a `UIWebView` and store the text as an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSTextStorage class to store the formatted text in your NSTextView.

Comment: The OP notes this is an iPhone app. iOS doesn't have `NSTextView`, it has `UITextView` which cannot display formatted text.

Comment: whoops.  Then your best bet is to use a UIWebView like what Rob Napier said.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Text
[Core Text Tutorial for iOS: Making a Magazine App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app)